# MongoDB aggregation on multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to create aggregation that runs on multiple collections with similar structure. I know about the `$lookup aggregation`, but i actually do not want to join between the documents, but to make a list of all the documents from all the collections. To better clarify my intention, I'll use an example.

Students collection:

```
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("57278a449fb5ba91248b3bc0"),
     "age": 22
}
```

Teachers collection:

```
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("57278a449fb5ba91248b3bc0"),
     "age": 28
}
```

I want to create an aggregation that will give me the average age of both of the collections together. How can i do it without using two aggregations and combine the results with my code?

Comment: this is not possible, you'll ahve to do this in 2 separate queries

Comment: Not possible if you check aggregration syntax : Model.aggregrate . It means u r doing aggregration on particular model

Comment: @Sam If you're specifying _Model_ then that is mongoose syntax, not mongodb native.

Comment: I was thinking about combination of $lookup and $unwind, is it possible to insert one collection into list of one documnet and than unwind it into seperate documents?

Answer (score 5):

You can get away with using new pipeline style lookups like this:

```
db.getCollection('students').aggregate(
    [
        {
            $group: {
                '_id': 0
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'students',
                let: {},
                pipeline: [
                    { $group: {
                        '_id': 0,
                        'avg': { $avg: '$age' },
                        'count': { $sum: 1 }
                    } }
                ],
                as: 'students'
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'teachers',
                let: {},
                pipeline: [
                    { $group: {
                        '_id': 0,
                        'avg': { $avg: '$age' },
                        'count': { $sum: 1 }
                    } }
                ],
                as: 'teachers'
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path : '$students',
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path : '$teachers',
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                'avg_age': { $divide: [
                    { $sum: [
                        { $multiply: [ '$students.avg', '$students.count' ] },
                        { $multiply: [ '$teachers.avg', '$teachers.count' ] }
                    ] },
                    { $sum: [ '$students.count', '$teachers.count' ] },
                ] }
            }
        },
    ]
);
```

The first `$group` stage gives you single empty document to start from, so each `$lookup` is only executed once. You can combine the averages from each collection by weighting by the count, this gives the same result as if taking the average over all the documents.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's now 2022, when I tried your answer. Unwinding $student returns the correct results, but when subsequently unwind $teachers, $student's data are no longer returned.